# Determine the lowest value of $ A $ such that $ f (x) \geq20 $ for all $ x> 0 $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functions

Be the function
$$\begin{array}{lrll}f:&(0,+\infty)&\longrightarrow&\mathbb{R}\\&x&\longmapsto&f(x)=3x^{3}+\dfrac{A}{x^{3}}\end{array}$$
where $ A $ is a positive constant. Determine the lowest value of $ A $ such that $ f (x) \geq20 $ for all $ x> 0 $

It seems to me that I have to limit the function to values ​​greater than or equal to 20, so, I suppose I need to optimize the function, right? that is, take first derivative and choose the appropriate minimum.

Comment: Yes, with appropriate considerations for what happens when $x \to 0$ and $x \to \infty$ this is a very good idea. Can you do this or do you need help?

Comment: I would like to give some clues maybe ... because, the analysis in the extremes of the interval I did not understand you very well.

Comment: hey did you understand my solution ?? or you are looking to solve it by another method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the A.M. G.M. method because here $x^3$ and $\frac{A}{x^3}$ are positive.

$$\frac{3x^{3}+\dfrac{A}{x^{3}}}{2}\ge (3A)^{\frac{1}{2}} $$
$$3x^{3}+\dfrac{A}{x^{3}}\ge 2(3A)^{\frac{1}{2}} $$
thus $$2(3A)^{1/2}\ge20$$
$$3A\ge 100$$
$$A\ge \frac{100}{3}$$

Comment: What's the meaning or what is A.M.G.M. method?

Comment: Arithmetic mean and the geometric mean, of course, you can solve it by differentiating the function and finding the point where $f'(x)=0$ and so on

Comment: I just derived and got that $ A = 3x^{6} $ but I got stuck there.

Comment: hey you are going in the right way   $x^3=\sqrt{A/3}$  put in the equation $f(x)=3\sqrt{A/3}+\frac{A}{\sqrt{A/3}}=2\sqrt{A3}$

also there was a typo in my solution  check out the updated solution of mine

Comment: Thank you very much!!

 excuse a question ... as weapons directly the inequality, $ \frac{f (x)}{2} \geq\sqrt{3A} $ the next step if I understand

Comment: Sorry, what is your question again didn't understand what are you asking?

Comment: How did you make the first inequality?

Comment: wikipedia pages are always awesome  read it you will understand better https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means

Comment: Ahh !! ... now everything makes sense, I forgot that, I'm sorry.

Thank you very much!!!...

Answer (score 2):

*Using algebra.*

Consider the function
$$f(x)=3x^{3}+\dfrac{A}{x^{3}}$$ $$f'(x)=9 x^2-\frac{3 A}{x^4}$$ $$f''(x)=\frac{12 A}{x^5}+18 x$$ The first derivative cancels when
$$9 x^2-\frac{3 A}{x^4}=0 \implies x_*=\left(\frac A 3 \right) ^\frac 16$$ For this value
$$f(x_*)=2 \sqrt{3A}$$ and the second derivative test shows that $x_*$ corresponds to a minimum. So, you want $2 \sqrt{3A} \geq 20$; then $A$.